# Survivor function of hitting time(i.e. first passage time) for a standard SDE

Tags: survival, brownian-motion

Take a standard stochastic difference equation,
$$
d z(t) = \gamma dt + \sigma d W(t)
$$
with $W(t)$ standard brownian motion.

Take an initial condition $z(0) = z_0$ and a threshold $\underline{z} < z_0$.  Define the stopping time $T$ as the first time that $z(t) \leq \underline{z}$.

**Question:** What is the survivor function of the stopping time?  Alternatively, you could give me the CDF and/or PDF.

**Note:**  This seems like such a standard problem, that I thought this would have an easily found formula. e.g. a variation on the Bachelier-Levy formula, or the corollary 7.2.2 in Shreve's stochastic calculus for finance.

Certainly plenty of versions with drift exist.  However, I cannot find a variation of the formula with the variance $\sigma$.  I would rather have a reference to the formula to ensure I don't make a mistake in any derivation.

Comment: $T$ follows an [inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution#Relationship_with_Brownian_motion)

Comment: @JarleTufto Perfect, thanks.  Post a solution so that I can accept it.

Comment: I don't remember the details but I think a derivation can be found in [Karlin & Taylor](https://www.amazon.com/Second-Course-Stochastic-Processes/dp/0123986508)

Comment: This [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23286/a-question-regarding-the-hitting-time-formula-in-brownian-motion/23291#23291) has a derivation using the "reflection principle" for Brownian motion without drift.

Comment: Found it: Karlin Taylor, first course. Theorem 5.3.  Thanks!

Comment: @JarleTufto  This turned out to be much more subtle than I realized.  I posted a separate question which summarizes the issue in: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909097/expectation-of-first-passage-time-of-a-diffusion-process-with-negative-drift  if you are interested in something more challenging.